# How can I make a nautilus-like sidebar using mono gtk#

Tags: linux, mono, gtk#, sidebar, nautilus

I have been looking for weeks for a way to do this:

[Screenshot http://img229.imageshack.us/img229/2430/screenshoteor.png](http://img229.imageshack.us/img229/2430/screenshoteor.png)

I am working on a music player, and would like something like this:

```
 Library           >
   Music          (6)
   Videos         (2)
 Playlists         >
   new playlist...
```

And so on. I am using mono and gtk#. I can't find a tutorial or anything, if someone could help me find one or give me an example that would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to use the gtk treeview. 
This is the tutorial: http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp_TreeView_Tutorial

Bye

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for an example, you might want to look at how [Banshee](http://banshee.fm) (a music player written with Gtk#) does things. From a quick glance, it looks like [this](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tree/src/Core/Banshee.ThickClient/Banshee.Sources.Gui/SourceView.cs) is the sidebar, but don't quote me on that.